# Как задать width: 100% для тега pre

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, frontend

Хочу отобразить код на странице. В мобильной версии сайта pre упирается в границы viewport и не хочет уменьшаться. Даже если оставить pre пустым, то его минимальный размер равен примерно 360px. Переопределить стиль не получается, чтобы ширина pre была равна ширине родителя. Можно только жестко задать размер в px, но мне это не нужно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А где html и css для pre? На скриншоте у вас разметка для гистограммы она какое отношение имеет к pre?

Comment: можно скинуть ссылку на саму страницу?

Comment: Просто добавьте в вопрос кусок кода (желательно без всего лишнего).  Скидывать ссылку в таком случае невежливо -- вам нужна помощь, а вы как бы говорите "ну сами поищите, где там у меня проблема".

Comment: мне нужна помощь, но я не хотел вас просить, чтобы вы сами поискали. там достаточно много кода, есть reset.css и несколько родителей, которые могут влиять, поэтому я не могу кусок кода без всего лишнего скинуть. 

вот можно вот так вопрос сформулировать, я смоделировал ситуацию в codepen: https://codepen.io/v-mokrushin/pen/jOKOVXg

проблема заключается в том, что если в devtools сужать viewport, то на ширине 304 px pre перестаёт сжиматься. как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Вроде бы всё сжимается. Какой у вас браузер?

Comment: проверил в chrome, yandex, ms adge, firefox. сжимается до 302 px, а дальше - нет

Comment: Вы проверяете свой пример из codepen или свою страницу? Пример в codepen сжимается (там есть пердел сжатия самого интерфейса codepen, но ваш pre сжимается хоть до 0). Вероятно вы не смоделировали ситуацию и упускаете какие-то важные детали.

Comment: у меня до 302px сжимается, если посмотреть в devtools. мы почему-то не понимаем друг друга ахах )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот как можно задать with=100% для тега pre:

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
}

pre {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <pre>
Принимая во внимание искусственность границ элементарной почвы и произвольность ее положения в пространстве почвенного покрова, тензиометр создает удельный микроагрегат.
Мир, как следует из вышесказанного, непредвзято оспособляет шаг смешения. Гумусированность вырождена.</pre>
<div>
```

И при этом, как видно, pre поместился в 300px. И даже поместится в 200 и в 100!

Может случиться, что контейнер не сжимается по какой-то своей причине (например, для него задана минимальная ширина). Тогда и pre внутри него не будет уменьшаться (он же занимает 100% от контейнера). В этом случае проблема не в pre, а в контейнере.

Comment: отлично, спасибо  )